# How to put < tr > tag if reach end of table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Just learning html+Jquery

the meaning is whenever I press button it adds a `<td>` tag in first column.
What I want to do is, if I reach the end of the table or `<th>`, I just want to put the next column.

```
$(".chkbox").click(function(){
  var value = $(this).val(),
      $list = $("#tablebody")

  if (this.click) {
    $list.append("<td data-value='"+ value + "'>"+ value + "</td>")
    $(this).remove()
  }
})
```

---

```
<table class="classytable" style="margin: 0px auto;">         
<caption>Сонгосон сонголт</caption>                                     
    <thead>   
        <tr id="colorfultr">
            <th scope="col">1</th> 
            <th scope="col">2</th> 
            <th scope="col">3</th>
            <th scope="col">4</th> 
       </tr>
    </thead>   
    <tbody id='tablebody'> 
     Inserted <td> goes in here
    </tbody> </table>
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] with a better explanation of expected behavior

Comment: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJFT4.png] this is picture of table what i want to show like top one. Right now its like bottom one endlessly adding <td> into 1 first column

Comment: Please post your current HTML and expected output

Comment: `<table class="classytable" style="margin: 0px auto;"> 
  <caption>Сонгосон сонголт</caption>
  <thead>
    <tr id="colorfultr">
      <th scope="col">1</th>
      <th scope="col">2</th>
      <th scope="col">3</th>
      <th scope="col">4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id='tablebody'>
  </tbody>
</table>` and output is like empty with td when i press button it add td in first column.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show formatted HTML there so that it is readable. Are you saying that on click you want to add one new `<td>` element, and it should be added to the current last row if that row has less than X cells already, otherwise it should be added to a new blank row?

Comment: @nnnnnn thank you for replying and forgive my dullness and broken English. I did what you said in edit

Comment: Your question is not clear and couldn't understand what you want to achieve. Please re edit it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My interpretation of your question is that on click you want to add one new `<td>` element in the table's body, and it should be added to the current last row of the table if that row has fewer cells than the heading row, otherwise it should be added to a new blank row. So as you add more and more cells they should "wrap" around to new rows.

To implement that you can do something like this:

```js
$(".chkbox").click(function() {
  var value = $(this).val(),
    $list = $("#tablebody"),
    $lastRow = $list.find("tr").last(),         // get reference to last row
    columnCount = $("#colorfultr th").length    // get number of columns
    
  if ($lastRow.length === 0 ||                       // if there are no rows
      $lastRow.find("td").length >= columnCount) {   // or last row is already full
      $lastRow = $("<tr></tr>").appendTo($list)      // add a new row
  }
  $lastRow.append("<td data-value='" + value + "'>" + value + "</td>")
  //$(this).remove()
})
```

```css
th, td { width: 50px }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Clicking a button will add its text to the table:</p>
<button class="chkbox" value="A">A</button>
<button class="chkbox" value="B">B</button>
<button class="chkbox" value="C">C</button>

<table class="classytable" style="margin: 0px auto;">
  <caption>Сонгосон сонголт</caption>
  <thead>
    <tr id="colorfultr">
      <th scope="col">1</th>
      <th scope="col">2</th>
      <th scope="col">3</th>
      <th scope="col">4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id='tablebody'>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Note that for demonstration purposes in my snippet I have added buttons and commented out the `$(this).remove()` from your code because if the buttons are removed on click it's hard to keep adding cells...

Comment: Having less `<td>`'s than the row requires makes for poorly formed html.  It would be better to have the correct number and fill the next available cell

Comment: Thank you its what i trying to say. Don't worry about remove(). The other function will get value of that button to show on another table when its got removed and i got lot of buttons to show in sequence ordering to user . its some kind of test

Comment: i achieved what i tried and do i need to close this as answered or ?

Comment: @MunkhdelgerTumenbayar - Read the following: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers